# SQL Server query with multiple HAVING conditions

Tags: ssms, having

Let's say we have a `Table1`:

```
ID Month Code
----------
1 Dec 

1 Jan Yes

2 Dec

2 Jan
```

How do I SELECT `ID's` with (`Dec` and `Jan`) and missing a `Yes` code? I'd like my query to return `ID 2` but not `ID 1`. I know I can't have an `AND` in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Month = "Dec" AND Code <> "yes" AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Month = "Jan" AND Code <> "yes")
```

Comment: In reality, the table that I'm looking at has ID's associated with multiple months (ID 1 with Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.). I want my query to pull ID's with (Dec AND Jan) and without a Yes code associated with it. So the IN operator wouldn't work in this case. Also, the Yes code could be placed on any month, not just Dec or Jan.

Comment: This gets me closer, but what if ID 2 has a Yes code on a month other than Dec or Jan? That's the tricky part of this query. Because I do not want to isolate the code logic just to Jan and Dec months.